# python doc for docstring

Tags: python, comments, doc

I want to have a tool which can generate documentation from the source code comments, I found a tool named pythondoc, it can generate HTML or XML from python source codes, but it doesn't support extracting the docstring, only supports extrats the '#'comments, is there a tool which can support the docstring extracting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily scan all your files and folders, find all python files, and get only docstrings out of them with some regex matching, something like this:

```
import re
import os
import xmlutils # download it from: https://gist.github.com/huseyinyilmaz/1448723

my_dir = '<absolute path to my dir>'

doc_dict = dict()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_dir):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r') as py_file:
                basename = os.path.basename(filename)
                doc_dict[basename] = [m.group('doc') for m in re.finditer(
                    re.compile(r'("|\'){3}(?P<doc>.*?)\1{3}', re.DOTALL),
                    py_file.read()
                )]

dict2xml(dict(root=doc_dict))
```

Comment: Please comment before adding -1, so I could fix what is wrong with my answer. Thanks.

Comment: He wants output in Html or xml, I would guess is the reason.

Comment: I added that, please give me my reputation.

Comment: This would grab all triple-quote strings, which need not be doc-stings. Also, doc-strings need not be triple-quoted.

Comment: I've just improved it, so now this script can catch single and double quoted strings as well. @DavidZwicker as PEP 257 says in http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/ -- *'For consistency, always use """triple double quotes""" around docstrings. Use r"""raw triple double quotes""" if you use any backslashes in your docstrings. For Unicode docstrings, use u"""Unicode triple-quoted strings""".'*

Comment: @DavidZwicker Now I realised, what is your point: in python only the first string statement is a docstring. But if you use triple-quoted strings elsewhere, my script will also catch those, even if they are not docstrings.. well, that's a problem.. I guess in that case it can not be caught with regexes.. +1 for that.